# What's a control system architecture that can track a ramping reference signal?

Tags: control-engineering, pid-control

It's well-known that a control system with integral control can track a constant reference signal (command) with zero steady-state error.

What is needed to generate a controller that can track a ramping reference signal (i.e. one that changes at a constant rate) with zero steady-state error?

Comment: This Controls Tutorial on Steady State Error is useful: http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?aux=Extras_Ess

Answer (score 3):

Consider a controller $C(s)$ for plant $G(s)$ and feedback $H(s)$.

The closed loop is

$$\frac{Y(s)}{U(s)}=\frac{CG}{1+CGH}$$

The ramp is $U(s)=\frac1{s^2}$

Thus the error is

$$E=Y(s)-\frac{1}{s^2}=(\frac{CG}{1+CGH}-1)\frac1{s^2}$$

According to the final value theorem,

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} e(t)=\lim_{s\to 0} sE(s)=\lim_{s\to 0} (\frac{CG-1-CGH}{1+CGH} \times \frac1{s})=0$$

For a known case, you can find out how many $s$ in the denominator of $C$ will reduce the steady state error to zero.

Comment: Feedforward might also be a solution (so that the feedback controller only has to attenuate disturbances).

Comment: @fibonatic, True, this can include $H=0$.